# ckeditor doesn't work on french browser

Tags: ckeditor

I just installed ckeditor on my server but the wysiwyg editor doesn't replace the textarea. It's something basic and I don't understand why.

EDIT : apparantly, the problem is linked with the language of the browser. English brwoser are ok, french not ! Any thought ?

Here is my page: http://cliniquelactuel.com/testckeditor/samples/

Here is the code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor Sample</title>
        <script src="http://cliniquelactuel.com/testckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body id="main">
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It works like a charm!

Comment: not on the page http://cliniquelactuel.com/testckeditor/samples/ it's blank

Comment: No, I have an editor in it. Change your browser and test it.

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot of what you see? It works fine on our browsers...

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you try a different browser? Does it happen on another computer? Open your browser's developer tools (F12) and check the console for errors. Try to disable any browser plug-in that might prevent a script file from loading, like ad blockers.

Comment: hum pretty strange, i just have a blank page. I tried with ff and chrome.

Comment: Apparantly it's linked to the language. I'm using brower in french, and it's not working.